# JSON format for time-logging

Tags: json

Hi I'm creating a very simple application that logs activities.

Right now I'm thinking I would just do

```
{"Activity":[
  {"ActivityType":"Sleep"},
  {"time_begin": someunixtime, "time_end":someotherunixtime},]}
```

and from there I could retrieve and calculate the date and the duration.

is that a sound decision?